# Validate individual element against xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a method that validates a XML Document against XSD.

```
public void validateAgainstXSD(String xsdPath, Document document) throws SAXException, IOException
{
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File(xsdPath)));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
}
```

This method is working fine. What I'm trying now is to validate individual element -

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(rootTag);
for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength();i++)
{
   Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
   //Validate only this element
}
```

And I'm clueless. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Validator.validate(Source source)`** takes an `javax.xml.transform.Source`, [***which can be either a document or an element:***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#validate(javax.xml.transform.Source))

> **Parameters**:
>
> source - XML to be validated. Must be an XML document or XML element
>   and must not be null.

**So, if you've gotten your code working for the document,**

```
validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
```

**you should be able to substitute an element in place of the document:**

```
validator.validate(new DOMSource(element));
```

**and validation should commence from there.**

Comment: Ohh! I didn't know that. I should have tried it. Thank you so much. I'll try it and let you know.